# Bumblebee (Optimus) Service Won't Start w/ 3.4 Kernel on Fedora 16

Tags: linux, fedora, drivers, nvidia, services

I'm using an ASUS laptop (MUXless graphics) w/ a GT 630M (re-branded 540M) GPU and only Fedora 16 installed. I installed bumblebee and the NVIDIAdrivers using the instructions described here: http://duxyng.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/finally-working-nvidia-optimus-on-fedora-16/

These instructions worked perfectly with the bumblebee service running properly between different subversion of the Linix kernel 3.3. If I load the kernel version 3.3.7 and 3.3.8 the bumblebee service will start and allow the `optirun` command to work. This does not happen with kernel version 3.4.2, and the bumblebee service fails to start.

This issue seems to have been brought up here:
https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/issues/23

I'm perfectly fine using the older kernels, but now I have to avoid any kernel updates. I'm wondering if anyone has any familiarity with this issue, it seems to be a rather recent one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have to ensure the fact that this kernels are compiled with a similar set of options, aka the config file that is used to compile the kernel

2) In this case, and in my experience, something can be wrong with the semaphores system or the BIOS/ACPI, at least this is the biggest suspect if you ask me.Also the BIOS and the ACPI are proprietary software so they can offer a real challenge if the manufacturer is not available to offer a better support.

There is also https://launchpad.net/~mj-casalogic/+archive/ironhide/ which is a fork from Bumblebee and probably is your best option at the moment.

EDIT: you can reach the source repos at https://github.com/MrMEEE/ironhide

Comment: I looked at `ironhide` package, the README file says "This will contain a cleaned, Ubuntu only, version of bumblebee". It doesn't seem like the best option. The second option seems to be out of the question. As far as I know my laptop has MUXless graphics. No options in the BIOS. Could you elaborate more on the first option.

Comment: @sj755 you can convert deb packages in rpm, if you do not want to spend some time figuring out how to customize this code for your OS, i think that you should wait for Bumblebee if Bumblebee is still alive.

Comment: you can also directly install debs under fedora with very few steps or with some utility like `alien`.

Comment: I haven't found examples of anyone using ironhide on fedora. Any chance that uninstalling and reinstalling bumblebee would do the trick?

Comment: @sj755 considering the user base of peoples using Fedora and an Nvidia Optimus video card and knowing about Ironhide i'm not surprised about this, you have to try, i do not have an Nvidia Optimus video card as i said and i can't try either, if you know a forum specialized about Fedora probably you can ask them and you can have a bigger chance of finding the people that have the same configuration and share your knowledge about the existence of IronHide.